# Is there a special name for stripboard with split tracks?

Tags: sourcing, stripboard

A friend of mine showed me a project he was working on, and the stripboard he'd soldered to had its tracks split into 3-hole blocks. A little like this:

```
=o=o=o= =o=o=o= =o=o=o= =o=o=o= =o=o=o= =o=o=o= =o=o=o=
=o=o=o= =o=o=o= =o=o=o= =o=o=o= =o=o=o= =o=o=o= =o=o=o=
=o=o=o= =o=o=o= =o=o=o= =o=o=o= =o=o=o= =o=o=o= =o=o=o=
=o=o=o= =o=o=o= =o=o=o= =o=o=o= =o=o=o= =o=o=o= =o=o=o=
```

<sub>*(apologies for the terrible ASCII-art)*</sub>

He can't remember where he got it from, but it looks incredibly useful! I've tried searching my usual sources (Farnell / RS / eBay) but I can't find it.

Does this stuff have a proper name?

Comment: Aha! Found this: http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/150613598911 - only one I can find on eBay, but the description isn't very helpful in finding a more reliable supply of it.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stripboard) suggests 'TriPad' ...

Comment: Oh derp, I never even *thought* to look there. Yup, that looks like the stuff. Post it as an answer and I'll accept :)

Comment: Try www.reichelt.de for H25PS050. They call it 'punkt-streifenrasterplatinen'.

Comment: That's *exactly* why I love the German language.

Comment: It *looks* incredibly useful, but it isn't. Useable yes. Incredibly: hyperbole. The English translation of the German would be, roughly, "piece of shit". You want islands of at least four or five holes, plus some long runs of copper for power rails and any global signals.

Comment: The one my friend used had some uncut rails at the top and bottom of the board. I really hate cutting tracks, so it's nice stuff for me :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you take a look on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stripboard), they call it 'TriPad'

> [...] one variant is called a TriPad board. This is similar to stripboard, except that the conductive tracks do not run continuously along the board but are broken into sections, each of which spans three holes. [...]

Trying to search with it on Farnell/Digikey/RS doesn't bring up any hits. Here they doesnt seem to give this kind of board a special name. Digikey gives you a filter option '3 Hole Pad' thou.

Comment: Maplin sell 39x62 tripad boards for £4.49, and they have a store about 5 minutes from my workplace.

Comment: Maplin are still pretty useful on occasion. I just wish their stock levels weren't so pathetic (like, they have two capacitors of a particular value in stock and so on).